# Annoying annotation io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation which is too popular and duplicate with application side class name

Tags: java, annotations

Springboot uses some annotations for REST api, such as

```
  @PostMapping
  @Operation(summary = "an example api")
  public void forceDone(@RequestBody @Valid final Example example) {
...
```

The @Operation is io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation.

But this name is too popular, the application side also have a class (not @interface) named Operation, such as

```
class MyApp.Operation {
...
```

Sure I can replace one side of them with full class name,

but I wonder

- ### is there anyway to tell Java to differentiate the @interface and class name? such as (pseudo code)

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.@Operation
import MyApp.Operation


...
@Operation(...)
... {
    Operation myAppOperation = ...  // not related to the @Operation.
}
```

(I understand that annotation can not be inherited, but still hoping a better solution).

EDIT: I have seen springboot internal source code searching for io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation, such as in `org.springdoc.api.AbstractOpenApiResource#calculatePath(..)`

```
            if (apiOperation == null || StringUtils.isBlank(apiOperation.operationId()))
                apiOperation = AnnotatedElementUtils.findMergedAnnotation(method,
                        io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation.class);
```

so obviously there seems no way to use an alternative annotation, I did not expect that.

But I come up with another thought:

- ### is there any way to reference annotation name by short name? such as

```
annotations.Operation
```

instead of

```
io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation
```

?

Comment: Seems no way to fix it, if no any answer, I am going to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas came to my mind.

**Idea 1:**

Create a meta annotation for `@Operation` with a different name and use this instead in your code base. This works only of the framework supports meta annotations / composed annotations. A quick test in my own Spring Swagger application looked promising.

e.g.:

```java
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Operation
public @interface OpenApiOperation {
  String summary() default "";
  String description() default "";
  // copy needed signatures of original @Operation here
}
```

Then use `@OpenApiOperation` instead of `@Operation` in your code base.

**Idea 2:**

Make your own `Operation` class an inner class and import it via the outer class name.

e.g.:

```java
public class MyApp {
  public static class Operation {
    // methods
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
import MyApp

...
@Operation(...)
... {
    MyApp.Operation myAppOperation = ...
}
```